# CSS with Superfish - menu works but arrows not showing

Tags: jquery, css, menu, superfish

Long-time reader, first-time question asker :)

I am attempting to install a Superfish drop-down menu to a page I am working on, and the menu is working perfectly, with the caveat that the little triangle arrows are not displaying next to the link text. I searched the web and found several others having an issue but they were all different problems. I can see arrows on other's menus that I've found on the web, and on the samples on the developer's site, so I feel like it's something that I have not done properly, or maybe a setting on my hosting server? I'm pretty proficient with HTML but still learning CSS, so I'm calling in the experts.

Here's the page in question with the simple menu:
http://laeca.org/sample.html

Any suggestions as to what I may be missing here?

Thanks!

JB

Comment: You need to provide code that replicates problem, and if you look at the browser's console you'll see that you're missing the jquery library

Comment: Hmm, I've not ever worked with jquery. So I need to add a < script > line with jquery.js?

Comment: yes, it looks like the libraries you're using need it

Comment: this being my first time, is there anything I can do to help you, such as a rep point, etc.? Help a noob out! :)

Comment: i'll add my comment as an answer and you can mark it as as response

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to provide code that replicates problem, and if you look at the browser's console you'll see that you're missing the jquery library

Answer (score 0):

I do not see anywhere in the css where you're attempting to create a triangle via borders. You'll need a border-left, border-right, and border-bottom to achieve this.

something like this...

```
<div class="arrow-down"></div>

<style>
.arrow-down {
    width: 0; 
    height: 0; 
    border-left: 10px solid transparent;
    border-right: 10px solid transparent;

    border-top: 10px solid #f00;
}
</style>
```

Comment: I see what you are getting at. I added another menu next to it with your suggestion. The arrows should be appearing automatically, based on the built in code of the menu. The desired result should look like these two examples: http://www.nevaeyc.org/teach/  and   http://users.tpg.com.au/j_birch/plugins/superfish/examples/

Comment: Got it. Juan C (above) pointed out that I was missing the jquery.js library reference. Thank you for taking the time to reply!